# SharePoint Calculated Column Not Posting Date Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have created a task list. I created an extra column that I want to calculate the value for. When the "Completed" checkbox for the task item is checked, I want to set the value of the Completed Date column for the task item to the today() when it is checked. I have the following but all that yields is a 0.

```
=IF([Completed]=1,TODAY())
```

Comment: You should not use Today() for calculating the date here because this date will be calculate again: 1. every time the item is updated after marking it as completed. 2. calculated column formula is updated

Comment: Also, the syntax of formula is wrong. You have to use IF function in this format: `=IF(<condition>, <true-value>, <false-value>)`. You are missing `<false-value>` (else value) in your formula.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. How would you recommend getting the right value, or is that even plausible.

Comment: Use customized list forms. If you are using modern experience, customize using Power apps. if using classic experience form, customize using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a calculated column for this purpose. You need to create the logic in the SharePoint form, so when the user ticks the box, the current date (and not the Today function) is written into a date column. To achieve this, you will need to use a regular date column (not a calculated column), and customise the SharePoint list form with PowerApps.  In PowerApps you can the build the logic you need to fill in the date when the box is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

You could set completed date column default value in the PowerApps as following picture shows.

[image]

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.